# How to divide mongo documents across multiple collections?

Tags: mongodb

i've a collection that have almost 8kk records and at this point some operations (like write) are taking too long to complete, to work around this i thought in split the documents across multiple collections, for example;

all documents that have a specific key starting between a and e, will be on a_to_e collections, documents starting between f and j will be on f_to_j collections, and so on...

this implementation doesn't take much afford to do in code(python) but i was thinking if a resource like this is available on on mongodb somehow by "default", if yes how can i accomplise that and if no, this is a acceptable solution for this scenario?

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB server are you using? Splitting a single collection into multiple collections doesn't really change the working set requirements: you are still reading and writing the same data (with potentially more open files for `mongod` to manage). Using multiple collections will also make queries more challenging unless you don't need to work with ranges of documents that might end up in different collections. I would look into tuning your performance instead: investigate slow queries/commands and potentially increase resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate({"$match":{ name: { $in: 
[/^a/i,/^b/i,/^c/i,/^d/i,/^e/i]} }},{"$out":"a_to_e"})
**so on execute queries**
```

Comment: interesting, thank you for the advice, can you show me how can i iterate over a array and "move" the results for another collection? the document structure is this: `{id: 1, persons: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]}` i need to move everything from `persons` to another collection but not as a array

Comment: db.getCollection('persons').aggregate({"$project":{"persons.id":1,"_id":0}},{"$unwind":"$persons"},{"$out":"anotherCollection"})

Comment: This query only export the person with `id = 1`, how can i export everything?
is possible to edit the content of `persons` before `exporting`? for example, i want to add the current `id` on each object of `persons` before moving it to another collection...

Comment: db.getCollection('persons').aggregate({"$project":{"_id":0}},{"$unwind":"$persons"},{"$out":"anotherCollection"})